# Смена вида деятельности, нужен совет

Tags: работа

Добрый день!
Долго думал, как сформулировать вопрос, напишу коротко как смогу. Прошу сильно не пинать, на других форумах тема наверняка не раз поднималась, но аналогичных вопросов на ХэшКоде я еще не видел.

##### Коротко о том, чем я занимался и что умею.

В студенчестве почти все свободное уделял программированию - `C, C++, WinAPI`, `asm`, `Delphi` - мне это было жутко интересно, т.к. преподавали у нас один `Pascal`.
Слово `Web` меня пугало, интернета у меня тогда не было, поэтому ограничивался только `Desktop` программированием, пользовался материалами, которые изредка скачивал у друзей, у которых был интернет (тогда еще dial-up). 
*Теперь*, проработав несколько лет, увидел, что, надо постоянно развиваться, изучать новые технологии и при этом еще успевать программировать. Это меня еще дальше оттолкнуло от `Web` программирования (мне всегда казалось, что там много шаманства). Тем не менее, пришлось изучать и новые технологии и научиться делать не очень сложные `ASP.NET` приложения.
Везде, где работал, занимал ведущие места, есть хорошее знание математики.

**К чему это все.** Профессия программиста меня начала утомлять, день проходит "работа - дом - покушать - спать". От этого и здоровье страдает и личная жизнь.
Такими темпами далеко не пойдешь.
Сейчас у меня есть достойная работа и там не надо заниматься изучением каждой новомодной плюшки и `Web`'а, проект типа какого-нибудь архиватора - нашел то, чем больше всего нравится заниматься.
Зарплата моя, по меркам города (живу в провинции), хоть и высокая, но жилье купить точно не хватит.

##### Тем временем.

Есть знакомый, лет на 5 младше меня. Он занимается обычной разработкой сайтов. Дело может и немного скучноватое, но он уже открыл свой офис, набрал людей, купил жилье, ездит в дорогом автомобиле. Да, у него конечно есть компьютер (у меня только со 2 курса) и интернет (у меня года 3 назад) уже со школы, но программировать он толком не умеет, а сайты на `CMS` штампует.

---

##### *В связи с чем возник вопрос, может мне тоже пора начать работать на себя, уйти от разработчика?*

Надеюсь у меня уже есть достаточно опыта, что бы организовать работу небольшой `IT` команды, настроить рабочие места, софт и т.д. Меня это привлекает, начать что-то свое, занять свою нишу. Начинать какой-нибудь стартап проект не хочется, больше привлекает занятие типа разработки того же сайта, где уже все пройдено (есть множество `CMS`, шаблонов, для нестандартных случаев наверное программируются не очень сложно), одна только проблема - найти клиентов.

- **Правильно ли я рассуждаю или это все мое узконаправленное мировоззрение?**
- **У кого какой опыт, что посоветуете?**
- **Отдельно хотелось бы узнать мнение тех, у кого есть свой опыт.**

**UPD**
Некоторые пояснения, вопросы можно немного переформулировать:
 - **Какова на самом деле реальность?**
 - **Не хотелось бы не повторять чужих ошибок, у кого есть опыт начала чего-то своего, кто чем занимается?**

Comment: Гляньте список IT тендеров на разработку/поддержку ПО в кэше гугла, там часто бывает так что цена неадекватно высока по сравнению с задачей которую нужно решить.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, можно на фриланс пойти? Я думал об этом, но не будет ли это такая же работа, только удаленно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы задаете такой вопрос, значит не уверены. Любой бизнес, будь это торговля шаурмой или строительство самолетов - это риск. Если у вас нет делового напора, наглости, то это не для вас. Ваш знакомый, я уверен, ни у кого не спрашивал, начать ему работать на себя или нет.

Comment: Да, не совсем уверен, для меня еще много вопросов есть, поэтому спрашиваю совета. Напор вот сейчас начал напирать. Мой знакомый, ну наглостью точно не отличается, а вот спрашивать наверное никого не спрашивал.

Answer (score 2):

Ваши рассуждения разумны, но вы забыли про, наверно, самое важное - **конкуренцию**. Сейчас есть очень много людей, которые думают так же, открывают свое дело и прогорают, потому что не могут донести до потребителей **чем они лучше** чем еще несколько десятков фирм из бизнес-центра напротив. Ответьте сами себе на этот вопрос, если можете, и вы сами поймете, стоит ли начинать.

Comment: Да, конкуренты это проблема. Как их можно "давить", маркетинг, новую фишку придумать, цена?

Comment: @ildar, не обижайтесь, но по данному комментарию сразу видно, как Вы далеки от *реального IT бизнеса в России* (про другие страны, даже постсоветские, достоверно не знаю).

У нас ведь все решается наличием друзей/знакомых среди потенциальных заказчиков и "конкуренция" идет на этом поле, поскольку у конкурентов в тех же структурах есть свои друзья.

Естественно, это не относится к "мелкорозничной торговле" (но там и денег-то нет).

Comment: Наверное, хочу в реальность. Да, у нас в России много чего решается знакомством. Но вот этот знакомый все начинал с нуля, без знакомства, его просто рекламировали бывшие клиенты. Бизнес его не большой, но и не "мелкорозничный".

Comment: @ildar, "обычная разработка сайтов", чем занимается ваш знакомый - это, в терминах @avp - "мелкорозничная торговля". Без обид. Шанс новой фирме получить большой вкусный проект стремится к нулю.

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, он в другом городе работает. Но ведь необязательно ограничиваться только своим городом? Пускай это "мелкорозничная торговля", начинать с него, потом можно расширяться. Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: если с нуля, то найдите клиента с большим или не очень объемом работы, но который может стать большим в перспективе - например "надо поправить что-то на сайте", а в перспективе "поддерживать" и или "дорабатывать этот сайт". т.е. чтоб и клиент от вас не ушел (качество, скорость, цена - лучше все три компонента) и какой-то поток денежный был...  
только до собственной фирмы тут процесс не близкий. без опыта (когда бывшие клиенты рекламируют) жирного клиента (ну или хотя бы упитанного) не подцепить.

Comment: есть другой вариант, купить какую-нить контору с историей. ну, типа берем мешок денег, главное не последний, и начинаем сами управлять, там уже и к квартирам с машинами можно присматриваться...

Answer (score 0):

не буду пытаться дать Вам ответ на поставленный вопрос, но немного раскрою пелену происходящего в сфере ИТ на данный момент ( возможно с большими погрешностями +-inf):
в настоящий момент отчетливо выделяются 2 направления по "легкой" монетизации труда программистов:
 - игровая индустрия: буть то консоли, PS, мобилки или браузерные игрушки
 - и собственно Web.

про 1ю сказать толком не могу ни чего т.к ни разу себя не применял для игростроя, да и одному там ловить нечего...
А вот про web говорить особо и не надо: огромный спрос на изготовление разномастных сайтов дает каждому адекватному фрилансеру место под солнцем (и не только фрилансеру)...
что-то знаете, что-то умеете, есть портфолио в данном направлениее - смело выкладывайте в сеть, первый заказ не заставит себя ждать.
чем специфичнее ваше направление и выше спрос на него тем дороже будет оплачиватся Ваш труд.
если соотношение цена/качество устраивает заказчика с большой вероятностью он обратится к Вам снова. При удачных раскладах через доволько короткий срок Вы обрастете своей стабильной клиентской базой и таким количеством заказов, что в одиночку этот объем вывезти будет тяжело - тут уже начинается предпринимательская деятельность: нанимаете других фрилансеров по более низкой ставке, контролируете их, маржу кладете в карман. при должном настырстве и умении себя продавать за пару тройку лет с нуля можно выйти на уровень хорошей веб студии и снимать сливки с труда окружающих.

P.S: из личного опыта - за 2 года на фрилансе поднялся с 45т.р/мес в офисе до $45/час работая в свое удовольствие. открывать офис не собираюсь.